# Use macros in a custom pallet tutorial doesn't compile

Tags: error, documentation

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/) but I have the following problem:

This is my `pallets/template/src/lib.rs` [file on github](https://github.com/viac92/substrate-node-template/blob/tutorialMacro/pallets/template/src/lib.rs)

And this is the `pallets/template/Cargo.toml` [file on github](https://github.com/viac92/substrate-node-template/blob/tutorialMacro/pallets/template/Cargo.toml)

The terminal error output:

```
error: expected one of: `generate_store`, `without_storage_info`, `storage_version`
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:40:12
   |
40 |     #[pallet::generate_storage_info]
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`
 --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use sp_std::vec::Vec;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `pallet`, `sp_std::vec::Vec`
 --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:4:9
  |
4 | pub use pallet::*;
  |         ^^^^^^ help: a similar path exists: `frame_system::pallet`
5 | use sp_std::vec::Vec;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0433.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0432`.
error: could not compile `pallet-template` due to 3 previous errors
```

I'm pretty new to Rust and Substrate so I don't get what is the problem here.

**UPDATE**

I remove `#[pallet::generate_storage_info]` as suggest by @shawn-tabrizi now I get only this two errors:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`
 --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use sp_std::vec::Vec;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |     use sp_std::vec::Vec; // Step 3.1 will include this in `Cargo.toml`
   |         ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `sp_std`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `pallet-template` due to 2 previous errors
```

Comment: Could you share the code via GitHub? Then its easier to help.  
The documentation about the `generate_storage_info` is outdated, you can replace it with the beginner-friendly `without_storage_info`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I just edit the question with link to the forked repo files.

Ok I will try to change in this `without_storage_info`

Comment: You can actually just delete `generate_storage_info` and not add `without_storage_info`. This would be better.

Comment: can you share the cargo.toml file? there is probably a mistake in there

Comment: It is in the initial question but here the [link](https://github.com/viac92/substrate-node-template/blob/tutorialMacro/pallets/template/Cargo.toml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you placed `sp-std` import into the `dev-dependencies` rather than the regular `dependencies`.

Your file should like:

```
[package]
name = "pallet-template"
version = "4.0.0-dev"
description = "FRAME pallet template for defining custom runtime logic."
authors = ["Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>"]
homepage = "https://substrate.io/"
edition = "2021"
license = "Unlicense"
publish = false
repository = "https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/"

[package.metadata.docs.rs]
targets = ["x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"]

[dependencies]
codec = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.0.0", default-features = false, features = [
    "derive",
] }
scale-info = { version = "2.1.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
frame-support = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26"}
frame-system = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
frame-benchmarking = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0-dev", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26", optional = true }
# PUT IT HERE
sp-std = { default-features = false, version = "4.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }

[dev-dependencies]
sp-core = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
sp-io = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
sp-runtime = { default-features = false, version = "6.0.0", git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.26" }
# DON'T PUT IT HERE

[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    "codec/std",
    "scale-info/std",
    "frame-support/std",
    "frame-system/std",
    "frame-benchmarking/std",
    'sp-std/std',
]

runtime-benchmarks = ["frame-benchmarking/runtime-benchmarks"]
try-runtime = ["frame-support/try-runtime"]
```

Comment: Thank you, I just started from the beginning and now it works.
Also the new versione of the tutorial is a lot better.